# Inicializar arrays Java

Tags: java

¿Por qué lo siguiente no funciona para inicializar un array?

```
public class TestArrays {

    private static int[] numbers;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        numbers = {1,2,3}; //error
    }
} //class
```

¿pero, sí de esta forma?

```
public class TestArrays {

    private static int[] numbers;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] arr = {1,2,3};
        numbers = arr;
    }
} //class
```

Comment: He empezado a contestar esta pregunta 2 veces y a mitad de respuesta me he dado cuenta que no tenía razón.... Espero con inquietud una respuesta correcta

Comment: Esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-java) de [so] tal vez ayude, habla de como inicializar arrays y de la forma correcta de la sintaxis

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Java permite inicializar un array usando llaves de la siguiente manera:

```
int [] array = new int[] {1,2,3};
```

Dicho formato, **sólo en el caso de que estemos declarando la variable**, se puede simplificar a

```
int [] array = {1,2,3};
```

En cambio, la primera forma sí funciona sin declaración:

```
int array[];
array= new int[] {1,2,3};
```

¿Por qué? Bueno, aparte de porque está definido así en las especificaciones del lenguaje, tendríamos que preguntar a su creador para encontrar el motivo que le llevó a restringir la forma corta a la declaración de variables. *Mi opinión* es que, si admitiéramos lo siguiente:

```
int [] array = {1,2,3};
array = {2,3,43};
```

no quedaría totalmente claro si en la segunda asignación estamos creando un nuevo array del mismo tamaño o si estamos reemplazando los valores en el objeto (array) que ya existía. Al obligarnos a poner `new int[]` se aclara la duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Muy útil a tener en cuenta en el futuro!

Comment: Esto me suena a una de esas imposiciones que hace java en favor de la claridad y la consistencia sintáctica... forzar a especificar el tipo para que quede claro que es un array de enteros y que se está creando un objeto

Answer (score 3):

Para complementar la respuesta de @Pablo Lozano. La especificacion de java establece la sintaxis correcta y donde se ocupa, en los siguientes parrafos:

[JLS 10.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3,
>   §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create
>   an array and provide some initial values.

Que en español sería:

> Un inicializador de arreglo puede ser especificado en una declaracion
>   (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4), o como parte de una expresion de creacion de
>   arreglo (§15.10), para crear un arreglo y proveer algunos valores
>   iniciales.

Donde definen el *array initializer* como:

```
ArrayInitializer:
    { VariableInitializersopt ,opt }

VariableInitializers:
    VariableInitializer
    VariableInitializers , VariableInitializer
```

Donde una *array creation expresion*, esta definida como:

```
ArrayCreationExpression:
    new PrimitiveType DimExprs Dimsopt
    new ClassOrInterfaceType DimExprs Dimsopt
    new PrimitiveType Dims ArrayInitializer 
    new ClassOrInterfaceType Dims ArrayInitializer

DimExprs:
    DimExpr
    DimExprs DimExpr

DimExpr:
    [ Expression ]

Dims:
    [ ]
    Dims [ ]
```